# Class inherited from a JAX-WS generated class not getting marshalled

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I have used wsimport to generate JAX-WS client code from WSDL.

I am invoking the web service with a parameter inherited from one of the classes generated by wsimport.

The class generated by wsimport is -

```
package com.mywebservice;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MOR", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class MOR {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    protected String type;


    /**
     * Gets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the type property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the type property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setType(String value) {
        this.type = value;
    }

        public synchronized boolean equals(Object paramObject)
  {
    /*equals implementation*/
  }

  public synchronized int hashCode()
  {

   /*hashCode implementation*/*/
  }

}
```

And I am passing instance of following class during web service invocation

```
public class TaggedMOR extends MOR {

private MOR moRef = null;

private String creatorMethodName = null;

public TaggedMOR(MOR MOR) {
    moRef = MOR;
}

public TaggedMOR() {
}

public void setCreatorMethodName(String methodName) {
    creatorMethodName = methodName;
}

public String getCreatorMethodName() {
    return creatorMethodName;
}

public MOR getMoRef() {
    return moRef;
}
```

}

I enabled http transport dump and saw that TaggedMOR was not marshalled in the SOAP envelope.

I also created an XMLJavaTypeAdapter but that also did not work.

Please advice, I am new to this.

Comment: Why are you extending the generated class? The whole point of generating code from a WSDL is to get the classes needed to call the service.

Comment: I basically need to do some profiling, and for that reason I am extending the generated code.

Comment: I figured it out, added @XmlSeeAlso in the generated class - MOR and then added a no-arg constructor in my derived class and removed the wrapping of MOR in TaggedMOR class.